# Using dlls in C # programs and checking problem

Tags: c#, dll

I created a dll function in a separate dll project, then created the program in C # and called .dll.

However, if the data you need to pass to the dll is wrong, the C # program will stop working and exit.

I tried to use the try catch syntax on the dll project side, but it was not what I wanted.
(What I wanted to do was to automatically pass the following information when the problem occurred)

I want to solve the problem that C # is forcibly terminated when the dll side does not receive a proper response or after a certain period of time.

If you know how to do it, I would appreciate it if you could give me your know-how and knowledge.

Thank you for reading. Answers I'll wait.  :)

Comment: Did you not understand my question .. John?

Comment: I think you want your try catch in your program code around the call to the dll. I'm guessing from your description that your call is throwing an exception that isn't being caught.

Comment: I didn't, I'm afraid.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking or what problem you're trying to describe.  Can you demonstrate with an example and indicate the specific error you get?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your problem is that your are trying to force incorrect data into a method from a dll which it resulting in an exception that is crashing the program. If this the case I would not put your try catch block in the dll , but rather around your call to the dll method.

If I understood the question correctly that should at least stop the program from crashing.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Correct description of the problem; however catching this is foolhardy.